# Cypress - How to get around with wait() after searching

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I have the below scenario:
I search for an element in search box. when the element appears (it may take some time), I click on the element which loads a new view. Then I try to click on some button in new view. since it takes some time to load the search result, the new view does not load. Any way I can avoid wait()?

This is what I have:

```
 cy.get('[data-cy="search"][data-component="input_box"]').type('Find me{enter}')
 cy.wait(200) // How to avoid this???
 cy.get('[data-name="Find me"]').contains('Find me').click()// Should load a new view 
 cy.get('[data-cy = "filter"]').click() // failing here as new view is not loaded
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Similar one:

```
describe('Tutorialspoint Test', function () {
   // test case
   it('Test Case1', function (){
      // test step to launch a URL
      cy.visit("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videotutorials/index.php");
      // enter test in the edit box
      cy.get("#search-strings").type("Java");
      // wait for some time
      cy.wait(3000); // ---> how to avoid this?
      // using jQuery selector to identify only visible elements
      // assertion to validate the number of search results
      cy.get('.clsHeadQuestion:visible'). should('have.length',19);
   });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a simplified example of your App? But basically, you just need to "wait" for the new view after clicking on the filter

Comment: It will be too much wait as I do this often :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't make it clear. I mean, waiting like `cy.get('your-view-page').should('exist')` after this assertion, your view page is ready and you can make more assertions for that page

Comment: You can learn more about how Cypress automatically retry your query (wait until it shows up) as I mentioned in the above in the docs https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html

Answer (score 1):

Could you try adding an extra timeout to the get? Something like:

```
cy.get('[data-name="Find me"]', { timeout: 1000 }).contains('Find me').click()
```

It's not a perfect solution, but sometimes adding a timeout like that can help.

Answer (score 1):

In similar situation you can use `cy.route()` which grab the network request and wait for it. In your case, the route will grab the n/w req and wait for the "Find me" request to get processed completely so that you can proceed with the next filter action.

Steps:
Open the chrome console, navigate to network tab, filter for XHR request. Now click on the ''Find me'' button in you page. You can see usually a GET request, for example if the request looks as follows, https://example.com.au/v1/api/listview?page=2
Please copy the url from `/v1/api/...` and add into the url value of cy.route() as below.

note: On click on Find me button, see its a GET or POST request, usually it will be GET request, check if the url has any encoded value, if it has encoded value you have to use `decodeURIComponent()`  and the pass the url inside as follows >> `url:decodeURIComponent('**/v1/api/listview?page=2**'),`

```
beforeEach(()=>{
    cy.server();
    cy.route({
     method: 'GET',
     url:'**/v1/api/listview?page=2**',
     delay: 2000
    }).as('getLoadNewView');
  })

    it('Route waiting for loading the new view for filter action', () => {
      cy.get('[data-cy="search"][data-component="input_box"]').type('Find me{enter}')
      cy.get('[data-name="Find me"]').contains('Find me').click()// Should load a new view 
      cy.wait('@getLoadNewView');
      cy.get('[data-cy = "filter"]').click();
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that there is some network activity going on on the background after you finish typing in the search bar. I usually wait for the request(s) to be completed and then check UI elements, when I have similar cases.

https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/12/23/asserting-network-calls-from-cypress-tests/, scroll down to “Waiting for the network call to happen” section.

`cy.wait('....')` is still there, but this time I wait for something explicit that effects the UI